# C pthreads: Start a Thread from main

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using an ARM processor with an Embedded Linux (C). My main program has to perform real-time operations and after a certain time duration (determined by the main program) I have to send data via a Bluetooth connection to an Android Tablet.

I thought to outsource the Bluetooth data transfer to a POSIX Thread. In the main function I have now to trigger the Thread to perform the sending of the data. So how can I 'restart' a Thread, because it should just send data via Bluetooth when the main function has to do it? That's why it also doesn't help to have a loop in the Thread function (combined with a sleep function) because, as I have already said, the timing is determined by the main function not the Thread function itself.

So is there an option to restart the Thread? Or maybe if anyone has a better idea to solve this issue I am open to it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest is with a synchronisation routine. Semaphore comes to mind:

```
thread() {
    for (;;) {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        send_data(...);
    }
}

main() {
    get_data();
    pus_data_in_a_buffer();
    sem_post(&semaphore);
    // ...
}
```

But if all you need to do is asynchronously send data you may want to have a look at the asynchronous IO library [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html).

Comment: Ah yes right that is actually a pretty easy and nice solution. In the main I can increase the Semaphore when a packet is available and in the Thread I just check continously of it is != 0. And if it is != 0 --> Send the data via Bluetooth. I hope this is how you intended it!? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to just have your thread loop, check if the send buffer is ready to send, and then pause briefly if it isn't ready. While not ideal for every circumstance, you certainly can let the thread keep looping and waiting for something to do.

Note that this is not practical for every case, but because you have mentioned that it is a real-time scenario, this may be your best option for maintaining peak performance, as semaphores can be somewhat expensive (in terms of processing time). If you do not need such optimization, you are probably safer using semaphores.

Comment: It is far from uncommon, and extremely lame.  Threads hardly ever need to loop/check/pause.

Comment: @MartinJames yeah but such a data communication, does not matter if it is a Bluetooth interface or RS232 (or whatever) I guess is a pretty common application for Threading. Isn't it? So what is now a better idea to do that?

Comment: Please do NOT design any more polling threads. Use explicit signals, mutexes, semaphores, events, etc. Want 8 hours of battery life in a laptop instead of 6? Don't poll.

Comment: It all depends on context. I once worked in an environment where we couldn't afford the performance loss of using semaphores and mutexes, so we had to rely on just looping and checking. That's far from ideal in other cases, but was nearly necessary in ours. Obviously our code wasn't being run on a laptop; it was designed for high-performance servers in a datacenter.